# How can I pass data to a component that is being reused?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm setting up navigation in my SPA (vue) that uses the `beforeRouteEnter` hook to call the backend and check if the user is authenticated.

When navigating from the login page to a protected page, this redirects to the same login page (if not authenticated). In order to explain to a user that they first need to be authenticated I would like to show a message.

Using `props`, passing data to the login page works. However, if this redirect goes from /login ==> /protectedRoute ==> /login no changes are made whatsoever because vue reuses this component. In most cases this behavior is desired, however in this perticular case it's not.

The `beforeRouteEnter` looks like this.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next)  {
  return axios.post('/api/auth')
  $.then(result => {
    next()
  })
    .catch(err => {
    next({name:"Login", params:{auth: "false"}});
  })
}
```

If I move from `'/guestRoute'` to `'/protectedRoute'`, everything works and the data is passed in the `'/login'` component after being redirected.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this can be done by using state management like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for vue.
You can call the assign the application level errors and they will be available to all your components.

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

This means your application data will be managed by one store.
Your application could have a store like this

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user : {},
    error: ''
  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  },
  getters : {

  }
})
```

So you can check assign any errors to the error property in store and add a check within a  component is there is a error or not.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, please?

Comment: Please do check out the vuex documentation too.

Comment: I see, I'll try implementing it like that. Thx for the reply!!